# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request in twitter api

Tags: asp.net, twitter

I am successfully authorized twitter api into my web application. But when i tried to get the Full details of a user it is turning out to be error 400 bad request.

After i got the access-token i am doing like this:

```
 if (accessToken.TokenSecret.Length > 0)
             {

              string url = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name={username}";
              HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
              request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
              request.Method = "GET";
              WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
              StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

i am getting error at

```
            request.GetResponse();
```

I gave the username correct..
What more data i am missing here??? 
Please somebody help me...

Comment: [`HTTPS`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/security/using-ssl)?

Comment: @EdSF thanx for ur reply..actually i first i tried with https as it gave same error the i thougt of change it to http,,no luck at all....same errorrrrrr

Comment: When i catched the exception i am getting web respnse as "{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Bad Authentication data\",\"code\":215}]}""